# Get deeply nested key value without for loop in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm not experienced with Python and I'm trying to directly query a key value from within a nested dictionary.  I'm working with the following:

```
"Items": {
  "Ingredients": {
    "M": {
      "sugar": {
        "S": "three quarters of a cup"
```

I can get what I need by using a `for loop` but if I know the key is named `sugar` how can I `.get()` to it directly?  It seems like wasteful cycles to use the `for loop` when you already know what you want.

EDIT: I'm querying a DynamoDB table and the response that I get is in dict form.  My search query is `results=client.query(**allmyargs)` so the name of my dict is results, if I'm not mistaken.

When I try `results['Items']['Ingredients']['M']['sugar']` I get an error that `list indices must be integers, not str`.

FINAL EDIT: I have much to learn.

Comment: `obj['Items']['Ingredients']['M']['sugar']` ?

Comment: Just access the keys directly? `data['Items']['Ingredients']['M']['sugar']`. What would you use the loop for?

Comment: OP, that is the whole point of dictionaries; *if you know the key, you can just get the value*. No loops, no nothing.

Comment: What do `obj` and `data` represent?  I was using the loop because I'm new enough that I don't know how to access the keys directly.  :\

Comment: Er, they represent the object you just posted.

Comment: `obj` and `data` are randomly picked names for whatever you called your actual dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, folks lol..   by object, do you mean the dictionary itself?  I'll update my post with more information to make sure I'm on the same page with everyone.

Comment: I believe my dict is named `results` but when I query using the method described above, I get an error stating that `list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Then you haven't given an accurate representation of the data structure. What about `results[0]['Items']['Ingredients']['M']['sugar']`? If that doesn't throw an error then you have a list containing the dictionary, but then you're probably not getting all the results that you want. You would have to show an accurate representation of the object.

Comment: Does that mean `results` is actually a list and not a `dict` despite the response syntax shown here?  http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query

Comment: The response I get from my query is as follows: `{u'Count': 1, u'Items': [{u'Ingredients': {u'M': {u'MacIntosh apples': {u'S': u'six cups'}, u'flour': {u'S': u'two tablespoons'}, u'sugar': {u'S': u'three quarters of a cup'}, u'lemon juice': {u'S': u'one tablespoon'}, u'nutmeg': {u'S': u'one eighth of a teaspoon'}, u'cinnamon': {u'S': u'three quarters of a teaspoon'}, u'salt': {u'S': u'one quarter of a teaspoon'}}}}], u'ScannedCount': 1}`

Comment: roganjosh - I get a KeyError when I insert the [0] as you illustrated.

Comment: You need to understand the basics of lists and dictionaries to make sure you understand exactly what the proposed approaches were trying to illustrate, then adapt it for your particular case (which was not given to us). `results['Count']['Items'][0]['Ingredients']['M']['sugar']['S']`

Comment: Note: If you copy your response into jsonlint.com and click "validate" it will give you a much more manageable structure to read. It's easier than pretty printing. Although the validation will fail here (json itself needs " not ' etc.) it will still format the structure.

Comment: Now I assume the next question is how to print all of the ingredients rather than just `sugar` and its amount? :)

Comment: roganjosh - thanks for that link!  I can post the more appealing format, if you'd like.  My case is that I'm trying to return the value of `sugar` directly without looping through every ingredient until I hit an ingredient that matches my a variable I have that's equal to sugar.

When I try `results['Count']['Items'][0]['Ingredients']['M']['sugar']['S‌​']` I get an error that `'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` which I'm assuming is because Count is returning integers?

Comment: Yes, I need to review what I typed now too :P I'll post an answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: roganjosh - I've managed to figure out the code I need to print all the ingredients (keys) and their amounts (values), but I lack the surgical precision for directly getting the key, value for a single ingredient.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual response object had a different structure than the example you posted, which meant that it was not possible to give an accurate method for accessing the data.

JSON and nested lists+dicts are quite hard to read. One method is to copy/paste to jsonlint.com and "validate". Even though this will fail for python objects, it's easier to read. I find this quicker than pretty printing, but that's an option too.

Based on your clarifications in the comments:

```
results = {u'Count': 1, u'Items': [{
        u'Ingredients': {
            u'M': {
                u'MacIntosh apples': {
                    u'S': u'six cups'
                },
                u'flour': {
                    u'S': u'two tablespoons'
                },
                u'sugar': {
                    u'S': u'three quarters of a cup'
                },
                u'lemon juice': {
                    u'S': u'one tablespoon'
                },
                u'nutmeg': {
                    u'S': u'one eighth of a teaspoon'
                },
                u'cinnamon': {
                    u'S': u'three quarters of a teaspoon'
                },
                u'salt': {
                    u'S': u'one quarter of a teaspoon'
                }
            }
        }
    }], u'ScannedCount': 1
}

# First get one of the inner dictionaries
ingredients = results['Items'][0]['Ingredients']['M']

# List of ingredients you are looking for
ingredients_wanted = ['sugar', 'flour', 'nutmeg', 'salt']

# Convert list to a set for faster lookups (not absolutely necessary, especially for small lists)
ingredients_wanted = set(ingredients_wanted)

amount_list = []
for ingredient, amount in ingredients.items():
    if ingredient in ingredients_wanted:
        print('Ingredient: {} \t in amount: {}'.format(ingredient, amount['S']))

print('\n')                
# Or directly without iterating the whole thing
for item in ingredients_wanted:
    amount = ingredients[item]['S']
    print('Ingredient: {} \t in amount: {}'.format(item, amount))
```

Comment: MISTER `f in` WIZARD!  Thanks a million, man.  I don't have enough cred here to sufficiently thank you for your tutelage and assistance.  That worked like a charm.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @AppleBaggins you're welcome. If the answer has solved your problem, then the stack overflow way to thank someone is to [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which you can do even if you're not able to vote on answers :) This also gives you some reputation and signals to others than the question is now solved.

Comment: Done!  Thanks for making my first post fruitful and educational!

Comment: @AppleBaggins no worries. You will see a lot of times people comment asking for an "M.C.V.E." for questions that are ambiguous. You can find details on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give tips on the things people are looking for e.g. in this case, accurate data structure (like the one in your comment. If it's a massive response, just a representative piece) and some code you tried that didn't solve the problem e.g. the `for` loop you wanted to avoid. That will help turn downvotes to upvotes next time :)

Comment: Consider me informed!  Hopefully, next time, I will know enough about Python to accurately present what I'm doing.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json 
r ="""{
"Items": {
  "Ingredients": {
    "M": {
      "sugar": {
        "S": "three quarters of a cup"
}}}}}"""
j = json.loads(r)


print j['Items']['Ingredients']["M"]["sugar"]
```

output

```
 {u'S': u'three quarters of a cup'}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to do it without importing more modules or libraries?

Comment: Either you need to use for loop or libraries